# How does the Kerberos authentication server pass additional account information?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I thought I understand how Kerberos works, now I am not sure at all.

We have a problem with Kerberos authentication on a 3rd party server with Windows Active Directory. The server support is insisting that what they call "kerberos server" passes additional information somehow, namely fields identified as `uid` and `email`, and I need to confirm that they are indeed "sent" by the server before they can help any further. I read "kerberos server" as the KDC, which "sends" information by placing it into the TGT, and the `uid` may be the good old UPN, except I do not understand why I am asked to confirm it *is* really there. But what is the `email` attribute?

I even read the whole [RFC4210](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt), but could not find any possible place for additional info in any of the tickets. In general, 1.5.2 talks about extending the protocol, but in the very abstract manner. There are also `KRB_SAFE` and `KRB_PRIV` messages, that can be used to pass arbitrary octet strings (3.4, 3.5), but no step towards defining their structure is done in the standard. There is also `padata` extension, that 5.2.7 notes *have also been used as a typed hole with which to extend protocol exchanges with the KDC.*, but this seems sent one-way. And nowhere the RFC seem to talk about additional identified fields that the authentication server can attach to the ticket.

My question is thus bifold:

1. Theoretical: how additional attributes are passed in Kerberos, presumably in an interoperable way (not e. g. Active Directory extensions)? **What** am I being asked to confirm?
2. Practical, if anyone can help with that: how to track what is placed by the AD into these attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server support is very lousy at telling you what they really want to have. Here is what you need: You want the KDC to send you PAC data with the generated service ticket. Here is Microsoft's reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237917.aspx.

How to verify? You need the a keytab for the account which is accepting the security context. Configure that with Wireshark, log all traffic. You should see the `TGS-REP` for the service you'd like to use. Expand it, when the keytab is fine, you will see the decrypted information. Somewhere down below, you should see the Authorization Data fields, type 1 (`AD-IF-RELEVANT`). That is an [ASN.1-encoded](http://lapo.it/asn1js/) sequence of elements. Even element position describes the sub type, odd element position the octet string. In that octet string is again an ASN.1-encoded suquence with type 128 (`AD-WIN2K-PAC`) and that is the PAC data. Unfortunately, Wireshark can decode upto level one only. The request is an opaque byte buffer. I have minimal, working (though incomplete) Java implementation of the PAC data decryption.

The email value is **not** included in that structure but what you have is the RID `KERB_VALIDATION_INFO` structure and the `userPrincipalName` in the `UPN_DNS_INFO` structure. The latter is extremely easy to decode.

First check via LDAP that for the desired client account [`userAccountControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223145.aspx) does not has the `NA` field set.

Godspeed.

Comment: @kkm I'd be interested to see your results.

Comment: Sure, I'll let you know!

Comment: It looks like we found what the issue was (a bug or maybe a feature in the server code) without having to decode and look at the packet capture. So I am sorry but I cannot give you any sensible feedback now. But thank you for the recipe to trace Kerberos exchanges in general, as issues with them are quite hard to diagnose!

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to decode and look at packet data?